# Prepare windows phone7 Application to upload to the market place

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to windows phone7 and just having some issues regarding preparing an app to upload to the market place.

**(1).** Bit confussed with the App version naming.

In the `WMAppManifest.xml`, there is "version" attribute under the App tag. Also when I check `AssembleInfo.cs` it has the followings

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I am not sure what is the difference between each of these three version numbers(one in WMAppManifest.xml file and others in AssembleInfo.cs) and should all contain the same value.

Also as far as I know, we should not edit these files manually and should change values via the application properties interface. But I didn't find any place in the application properties interface to change the "version" number of the "WMAppManifest.xml" file.

---

**(2).** All the important steps that have to carry out before create the final .xap file

- What is `<Capabilities>` section of the WMAppManifest.xml file and do I have to change anything there?

---

**(3).**  The steps that have to follow when go for a new Application update to the market.

---

Would be really grateful if someone can giude through this. Thanks inadvance....!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not at all issues, and there is nothing to worry regarding these things.

(1) App version is the one which you specify while submitting your app to the marketplace.

There is a column in the application submission process, which asks you the version of your app and you can choose a version number there. Nothing to do with your properties (as far as marketplace submission is concerned).

(2)  are the capabilities that your app uses or contains.
For example: Networking capability if your app makes any web requests from your code, or Camera capability if your app uses camera etc

Again these are identified from your XAP file and you need not worry about this.

(3) The above two applies when you are submitting an update. There is nothing special you do when submitting an update, the process is same.

Have a happy Submission. And I suggest you to be careful when choosing the keywords for your app, during submission process :)

Update:

Microsoft documentaion says:

```
The app version number is not extracted from the executable, so you’ll need
to enter it manually. If you're uploading an update to your app, adjust the
XAP version number accordingly.
```

So you don't have to worry about version number during submission. But you can maintain version in the XAP for future purpose. And I forgot to tell, In the app properties interface, there is a button "Assembly Information" which allows you to change your version number of the build. Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: You mean I don't have to provide any version number in these manifest files and let it to be the default(1.0.0.0). Because in Android we have to specify the version number in the manifest file, and in each update it has to increase version number. Also need to know even when we go for an update if need to change the version number anywhere in manifest file or assembley versions